# Switch beetween Screen on LibGdx application

Tags: java, android, libgdx, screen, render

i'm new of libgdx and this is my first app, but i have the problem with screen switch.

i have set main class like this:

```
public class MyClass extends Game {
    MenuClass menuClass;
    ActionGame actionGame;


@Override
public void create() {
        menuClass = new MenuClass(this);
        actionGame = new ActionGame(this);
        setScreen(actionGame);
    }
}
```

and method of ActionGame class like this:

```
....
@Override
public void pause() {
    game.setScreen(game.menuClass);
}

@Override
public void resume() {
    this.show();
    this.render(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
....
```

and method of menuClass.java like this, when touch Play button:

```
....
@Override
public void resume() {
    game.actionGame.resume();
}
....
```

When i touch play button i wish that actionGame class return in action render, but the render don't start.
I have try with setScreen, but this restart my screen, this not good. 
Help

Thanks

Comment: Seeing your new question, it would actually be nice if you could accept the answer to your old question. (Which lead to this new question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between screens Libgdx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837013/switching-between-screens-libgdx)

Answer (score 0):

You're using `resume` incorrectly. It is something that is always called when your app is brought back to screen. You should never call `resume()` on any of your classes yourself. It is called by Libgdx when your app is brought back to the foreground.

It is correct that you should switch to the menu screen in the `pause` method, because gamers expect the game to automatically go to a menu or pause screen when the app goes off screen. But you do not want to be automatically switching back to the game when the app comes back on screen.

The `resume` method would only be used for reloading stuff that you unloaded in `pause` (which you probably don't need to do), or to restart music, or something like that.

Your Play button definitely should not be calling `resume`. It should be calling `setScreen(actionGame);`. And there should be nothing in any of your `resume` methods as you have currently designed it.