# How do I change screen from main menu to game using libGDX?

Tags: android, menu, libgdx

I'd like to know how I can change the screen from the Main Menu to the Game itself but im having quite the trouble and I would appreciate the help. What I want to do is when I press *btn.Play* it changes the screen from the main menu to the game.

Here's the code I have:

Game:

```
@Override
public void create(){

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Up = new Texture("left.png");

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,1280,720);

    //creates the square in the middle of the screen
    square = new Rectangle();
    square.x = 630;
    square.y = 720 / 2 - 32 /2;
    square.width = 32;
    square.height = 32;

    //code
}

//code

public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Up, square.x, square.y);
    //code
    batch.end();
}
```

Screens (used to display the first screen) :

```
public class Screens extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game {


//creates the timing on the splash screen


@Override
public void create() {

    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();

    //sets the next screen as the splash screen
    setScreen( new SplashScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void render(){

    super.render();
    rendCount++;
}

@Override
public void dispose(){

    endTime = TimeUtils.millis();
}
```

SplashScreen:

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen  {


public SplashScreen(Game g) {

    myGame = g;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
}


@Override
public void show() {


    //image of the splash screen
    splashTexture = new Texture("splash.jpg");

    //timer starts
    timeStart = TimeUtils.millis();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    //draws the image on screen
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(splashTexture, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
    rendCounter++;

    // if the timer is higher than 5 secs goes to the main screen
    if(TimeUtils.millis() > (timeStart+5000)) {
        myGame.setScreen(new MainScreen());
    }

}

@Override
public void dispose(){

    splashTexture.dispose();

}
```

Main Menu:

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen{

private SpriteBatch batch;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private Stage stage;
private TextButton btnPlay, btnExit;
private BitmapFont font;
private Skin skin;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

public MainScreen() {

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280,720);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}


@Override
public void show() {

    // creates the pack for the buttons, its skin, the font used on the buttons, and the stage(screen)

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons.pack");
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.clear();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    // sets the style of the buttons

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    style.up = skin.getDrawable("btn_up");
    style.down = skin.getDrawable("btn_down");

    // sets the font of the buttons

    style.font = font;


    //creates the play button with the text, its position and the size

    btnPlay = new TextButton("Play", style);
    btnPlay.setSize(350, 150);
    btnPlay.setPosition(450, 400);

        btnPlay.addListener(new InputListener() {

            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new Game());
                dispose();

            }
        });

    btnExit = new TextButton("Exit", style);
    btnExit.setSize(350,150);
    btnExit.setPosition(450, 150);

    btnExit.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            Gdx.app.exit();
            dispose();

        }
    });

    stage.addActor(btnPlay);
    stage.addActor(btnExit);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    stage.act();

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    font.dispose();

}
```

In the MainMenu class when I use:

```
btnPlay.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new Game());
            dispose();

        }
    });
```

It crashes the app. Any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between screens Libgdx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837013/switching-between-screens-libgdx)

Comment: Ive been looking through some questions like that and I cant seem to find the solution for mine, just needed someone to check what I can change and how.

Comment: Well this looks like a mess doesn't it? First thing you should do is find out what exact line is causing your app to crash so that you can debug from there. I guess you've narrowed it down to a couple lines though. Why doesn't your MainMenu class take a Game object in the constructor like your SplashScreen class? Then in your touchUp method you would set the screen to a new gameplayscreen. You're setting it to a 'new Game()'. Well, a Game object doesn't actually do anything. The logic is all in a Screen. You need to make a new screen for gameplay and set the screen to that.

Comment: @Barodapride I did the same to the MainMenu class as it is on the SplashScreen class and it doesnt crash anymore although when I press the play button it just goes to a black screen and not the game itself.

Comment: Well you have to give it a real screen to go to. You can't give it a "game".

Comment: @Barodapride I gave it the Game class tho

Comment: All the Game class does is let you set the current screen. It's up to you to make the screens in your game. Obviously libgdx does not come with your game automatically. You need to create a MainMenuScreen, GameplayScreen, WhateverScreen. Then call game.setScreen(whateverscreen). To control the flow of your game. What you have currently - game.setScreen(new Game()) doesn't make sense. You need to do game.setScreen(<your screen you made>). The libgdx Game class does not contain a real game.